# Word adding newlines after replaced text?

Tags: microsoft-word, ascii-art

For a video game, I'm making an ascii map of 1s and 0s which the program makes a 3D labyrinth out of. This is obviously not fun to edit (100x100). To make it easier, I tried setting up Word's autocorrect feature to replace all zeros with blue highlighted zeros so I could see the map better. It does this, but for some reason it's adding a newline every time it makes a replacement, which completely counteracts the benefit by making me have to backspace every time I add a character.

Does anyone know why it's doing this, and how to stop it?

Or if anyone could just recommend a better way of editing grids of 1s and 0s, that'd be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-correcting a 0 doesn't really work for me as it will only auto-correct a 0 surrounded by spaces. But I cannot reproduce the line break either. What you can easily do is to do a search and replace with formatting, though. This won't change zeroes to highlighted immediately, but you could simply apply it a little frequently, then.

[image]

But to address your second question: For editing a grid of zeroes and ones I'd probably just use a bitmap image and use Paint, Paint.NET or whatever is appropriate. Then a simple script could convert the image into the necessary text file of zeroes and ones.

Comment: your first suggestion is good but there is no need to replace you can simply search for 0's and highlight all results

Comment: Mh, that would be easier still, I guess :). I'll test once I'm at work since.y computer is currently upgrading to Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

How about Excel?  Use conditional formatting to give zeroes a dark background, or whatever you'd like.  Set column widths to something very small, maybe 2.5, so as to get a roughly square grid.  As a bonus, it'd be much easier to insert a column.

Add a 101st column that concatenates each of the preceding 100.  To output your data, copy this column and paste it into a text editor.